# Installing 'Boost' library - using VSCode. Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost, include-path

I've been trying for several days to add a Path on VSCode to the 'boost' library I've installed for a practice I've got. I can't link up the code implementation with the library downloaded. It keeps printing on the Output: `fatal error: boost/signals2/signal.hpp: No such file or directory`. This is the c_cpp_properties.json I have:

```
    {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_66_0"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

In which I specify the route to 'boost' in 'includePath'. This is my tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "C:\\w64devkit\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-lboost_system"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Tarea generada por el depurador."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo ver(1)",
            "command": "C:\\w64devkit\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-lboost_system"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Tarea generada por el depurador."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And this is my code implementation:

```
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Very simple, but the problem is the linking from the compiler to the library. I don't know what to do

Comment: Perhaps try vcpkg to manage libraries - this integrates with VSCode

Comment: And how do I do that? Do you mind telling me briefly the steps?

Comment: @CaioLorenzoIriarteSalles Does it have to be visual studio code? If not mandatory, I can tell you how to do it for visual studio 19

Comment: dogu.bin, I already have the Visual Studio configured and ready to use (I installed it aiming to download the library on my machine Windows); I just wondered if there was any way of using it in VSCode, cause I'm more used to it. Thank you :)